# How do you filter a query based on zero or more terms in a RavenDB LuceneQuery?

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I need to filter a LiceneQuery by a users' favourited and blocked tags. I've got this working when a user has some favourite and blocked tags but I'm struggling with the case where the user has no favourite or blocked tags. I believe I need to use the equivalent of a MatchAllDocsQuery but I can't see how to achieve this through the RavenDB client API.

This works fine when the user has one or more favourite and one or more blocked tags:

```
string favesQuery = String.Join(" OR ", user.FavouriteTags.Select(x => String.Format("Tags:{0}", x)));
string blockedQuery = String.Join(" AND ", user.BlockedTags.Select(x => String.Format("-Tags:{0}", x)));
var articles = RavenSession.Advanced
                           .LuceneQuery<Article>("AllDocs/ByTags")
                           .Include(x => x.Author)
                           .Where(favesQuery)
                           .Boost(0.5m)
                           .Where(blockedQuery)
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePublished);
```

The immediate issue I'm getting, is `Missing where clause`, but this is because the `String.Join` returns an empty string when `user.FavouriteTags` is empty. Can I prepend something to `favesQuery` and `blockedQuery`?

Thinking in SQL terms, I'm looking for the equivalent of an `WHERE 1=1 AND ...`

Related question https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/JKTpHiFRJLc

Comment: It had crossed my mind. I wonder what the performance implications of this are?

Comment: should be zero performance implications, as the terms has be tokenized during index time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethink the structuring of the LINQ methods.

```
var articles = RavenSession.Advanced
                           .LuceneQuery<Article>("AllDocs/ByTags")
                           .Include(x => x.Author);
if (user.FavouriteTags.Any()) {
    string favesQuery = String.Join(" OR ", user.FavouriteTags.Select(x => String.Format("Tags:{0}", x)));
    articles = articles.Where(favesQuery).Boost(0.5m);
}
if (user.BlockedTags.Any()) {
    string blockedQuery = String.Join(" AND ", user.BlockedTags.Select(x => String.Format("-Tags:{0}", x)));
    articles = articles.Where(blockedQuery);
}
articles = articles.OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePublished);
```